# Checkboxes go down when checked | Alignment problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I have some textboxes in a column inside of a row and checkboxes in another column inside of a row and i want them to align in front of each other but the checkboxes go down when any of them is checked and this produces alignment problems.
This is the html code (Only contains the row and the column that has the checkboxes, it doesn't contain the text boxes that i want it to align in front of):

```
<div class="container" style="box-shadow: rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.3) 0px 1px 2px 0px, rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.15) 0px 1px 3px 1px; border-radius: 3px; padding: 50px">
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container" style="box-shadow: rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.3) 0px 1px 2px 0px, rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.15) 0px 1px 3px 1px; border-radius: 3px; padding: 50px">
        <form>
          <div class="row">
            <div id="has-allergy" class="row pe-0 align-items-center space-margin" style="margin-top: 32px">
              <div class="col-md">
                <div class="form-check" style="margin-top: -6px">
                  <input onchange="checkboxsChange()" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="allergy-input" id="allergy-checkbox" />
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="allergy-checkbox"> Alerjisi var </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div hidden id="allergy-details" class="col-md">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Alerji" style="margin-top: 5px" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="has-illness" class="row pe-0 align-items-center space-margin">
              <div class="col-md">
                <div class="form-check" style="margin-top: -1px">
                  <input onchange="checkboxsChange()" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="illness-input" id="illness-checkbox" />
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="illness-checkbox"> Hastalığı var </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div hidden id="illness-details" class="col-md">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Hastalık" style="margin-top: 6px" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="had-surgery" class="row pe-0 space-margin align-items-center">
              <div class="col-md">
                <div class="form-check" style="margin-top: -2px">
                  <input onchange="checkboxsChange()" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="surgery-input" id="surgery-checkbox" />
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="surgery-checkbox"> Ameliyat oldu </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div hidden id="surgery-details" class="col-md">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ameliyat" style="margin-top: 7px" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is the css code:

```
.space-margin {
  margin-top: 52.5px;
}
```

this is the js code (this is so that the textboxes next to the checkboxes show up when checkboxes are checked):

```
function checkboxsChange() {
  if (allergy.checked === true) {
    allergyDetails.hidden = false;
  } else {
    allergyDetails.hidden = true;
  }

  if (illness.checked === true) {
    illnessDetails.hidden = false;
  } else {
    illnessDetails.hidden = true;
  }

  if (surgery.checked === true) {
    surgeryDetails.hidden = false;
  } else {
    surgeryDetails.hidden = true;
  }
}
```

I spent a lot of time trying things, mostly checked if there was any margins or anything else causing this but could not fix the problem.
Any answer would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: I can't find the problem in the provided code, however, I recommend (it may not be seen as related to the problem) to clean more your HTML code more by at least moving your inline CSS code to the CSS file, this can give you a clearer view, also your HTML It's messy, please accept my humbled feedback